# Scala Set different operations

Tags: scala, set, operation

So here is my code snippet:

```
 val check = collection.mutable.Set[String]()
    if (check.isEmpty) {
      println("There is no transfer data available yet, please use the 'load' command to initialize the application!")
    }
    val userSelection = scala.io.StdIn.readLine("Enter your command or type 'help' for more information:")
    val loadCommand = """^(?:load)\s+(.*)$""".r
    userSelection match {
        case loadCommand(fileName) => check add fileName ;print(check);val l= loadOperation(fileName);println(l.length); if (check.contains(fileName)){
          programSelector()

        }else{ loadOperation(fileName)}
```

So first of all I have an input with the match and one case is the "load" input.
Now my program is able to load different .csv files and store it to a List. However I want my program whenever it loads a new .csv file to check if it was loaded previously. If it was loaded before, it should not be loaded twice!!
So i thought it could work with checking with an Set but it always overwrites my previous fileName entry...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `set` operations are fine.  The issue is the `check add fileName` straight after `case loadCommand(fileName)` should be in the `else` block. (One of those "d'oh" moments that we have now and then!?) :)

### Update

#### Code

```
val check = collection.mutable.Set[String]()
def process(userSelection: String): String = {
  val loadCommand = """^(?:load)\s+(.*)$""".r
  userSelection match {
    case loadCommand(fileName) =>
      if (check.contains(fileName))
        s"Already processed $fileName"
      else {
        check add fileName
        s"Process $fileName"
      }
    case _ =>
      "User selection not recognised"
  }
}

process("load 2013Q1.csv")
process("load 2013Q2.csv")
process("load 2013Q1.csv")
```

#### Output

```
res1: String = Process 2013Q1.csv
res2: String = Process 2013Q2.csv
res3: String = Already processed 2013Q1.csv
```

Comment: thank you, but whenever I print my "check" it is empty? I need to add it right after my input so isn't the order right?
And why is my Set always getting overwritten by the next input "fileName".
Besides my check.isEmpty isnt also working,idk why not but I am stuck there :(

Comment: Try print(check.size) instead of print(check) in case the stored element is not printable (e.g., None, empty string, null).

Comment: That means the matched string is always empty, can you println(s">>$userSelection<<") as well and we'll know better what's going on here.

Comment: thats the output:
>>load 2013Q1.csv<<<
I was loading now the file "2013Q1.csv"

Comment: just updated answer with code and output, hope it helps